# Multiple predictors that measure the same concept in regression

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, multivariate-analysis, linear-model

I have used three questionnaires in a study that all measure musical training. Each of these three questionnaires (MT1/MT2/MT3) consist of various Likert scales that are averaged to calculate the score of the questionnaire. Now I am interested how musical training is correlated with another variable S (sight-reading ability) in three different conditions. In general my linear mixed model would look like the following, if I had only one variable for musical training:

S ~ cond * MusicalTraining + (1|participant)

The scores of the questionnaires are not surprisingly correlated:

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.3615148 0.7092172
[2,] 0.3615148 1.0000000 0.5723699
[3,] 0.7092172 0.5723699 1.0000000
```

**EDIT**

Moreover, when calculating the reliability across all items from the three questionnaires (MT1/MT2/MT3) assessing musical training they show a Cronbach-Alpha of alpha = .86 95%CI [.8, .91].

**EDIT END**

It seems to me to be too complicated to use all three variables for musical training in the regression and I am also not to sure how to interpret the results of such a model, e.g. S ~ cond * MT1 * MT2 * MT3 + (1|participant).

I tried to run a PCA and use the first principal component in the regression. However, I think a PCA is difficult to interpret if then used in a regression.

Is there any other way to deal with this issue? Could I just average the different measurements of musical training for each each participant and use them as a single variable?

Comment: How is MT measured? Is this one numerical variable? If not, can you describe it?

Comment: @user2974951 There are three questionnaires that each assess musical training. They all consist of multiple Likert scales that are averaged to obtain the questionnaire score.

Comment: If you run a reliability analysis in which you enter all items from all the questionnaires simultaneously, what reliability estimate you get?

Comment: @Sointu If I just use the average scores of the questionnaires and calculate a Cronbach-Alpha I get a quite decent reliability of .78, 95%CI[.71, .84]. Or do you actually mean calculating the reliability over all items?

Comment: I meant calculating reliability across all items, yes

Comment: @Sointu I added the Cronbach-Alpha reliability calculation across all questionnaire items to the original post.

Comment: With that alpha & if there are no strong theoretical or other reasons to say these questionnaires would measure different things, I would definitely average all items (from all 3 questionnaires) into a composite measure and use that as the predictor.

Answer (score 3):

If you can reasonably assume that the three questionnaires measure the same dimension/latent variable representing musical training (MT), you could aggregate the three scores and use a single composite variable representing musical training. Alternatively, you could use the three scores as separate indicators of an MT factor (latent variable) in a structural equation model.

Before doing that though it may be a good idea to run item-level factor analyses with all MT items to see how many factors you would get at the item level (i.e., is there a strong single factor/dimension of MT or multiple factors at the item level?)